# Switching on scoped enum

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, enums, switch-statement

I am trying to switch on a scoped-enum with the type unsigned int:

The enum is defined as:

```
const enum struct EnumType : unsigned int { SOME = 1, MORE = 6, HERE = 8 };
```

I receive a const unsigned int reference and I am trying to check that value against the enum values.

```
void func(const unsigned int & num)
{
    switch (num)
    {
    case EnumType::SOME:
        ....
        break;
    case EnumType::MORE:
        ....
        break;

    ....

    default:
        ....
    }
}
```

This results in a syntax error: `Error: This constant expression has type "EnumType" instead of the required "unsigned int" type.`

Now, using a `static_cast` on each switch, such as:

```
case static_cast<unsigned int>(EnumType::SOME):
    ....
    break;
case static_cast<unsigned int>(EnumType::MORE):
    ....
    break;
```

fixes the syntax error, although casting at each case statement doesn't seem like a good way to do this. Do I really need to cast at each case, or is there a better way?

Comment: In my opinion the whole point of strongly typed enums is that they're ... well, strongly typed, so no implicit conversions. So yes, you do need to cast.

EDIT: I see now that you weren't asking whether you need to cast but whether you need to cast for each case. Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can solve this by casting the switch variable itself to `EnumType`:

```
switch (static_cast<EnumType>(num)) {
```

([Demo](http://ideone.com/LCKlZq))

The purpose of scoped enums is to make them strongly-typed.  To this end, there are no implicit conversions to or from the underlying type.  You have to convert either the switch variable or the switch cases.  I would suggest converting the switch variable since this requires less code and therefore will make maintenance easier.

IMO the correct solution would be to change the function to accept `const EnumType &` (or just `EnumType`) instead.